# SQL Server stored pProcedure with is null and equals operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need a stored procedure with 2 parameters, `@TId` is for top Id and `@CId` for CultureId which is selecting proper culture items.

I want my where clause looks like this when `@TId` parameter is null:

```
WHERE TopId IS NULL AND CultureId = @CId
```

but when I specify an actual int value for `@TId`, it should look like this:

```
WHERE TopId = @TId AND CultureId = @CId
```

I have an issue with Where clause shown by comment near it.

This statement is not working with error:

> Incorrect syntax near is

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE hierarchicalcategoryview
    @TId INT = NULL,
    @CId INT = 1    
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH HierarchicalCategoryTable (TopId, Id, Name, Level) AS
    (
        SELECT 
            c.TopId, c.Id, c.Name, 0 AS Level
        FROM 
            categoryview AS c
        --the where clause which fails
        WHERE 
            CASE 
               WHEN @TId IS NULL 
                  THEN (TopId IS NULL AND CultureId = @CId)
               WHEN @TId IS NOT NULL
                  THEN (TopId = @TId and CultureId = @CId)
            END

        UNION ALL

        SELECT 
            c.TopId, c.Id, c.Name, Level + 1
        FROM 
            categoryview AS c    
        INNER JOIN 
            HierarchicalCategoryTable AS d ON c.TopId = d.Id 
        WHERE
            c.CultureId = @CId
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM HierarchicalCategoryTable 
    ORDER BY Level ASC, Id ASC
END
```

Summary I can't dynamically change

```
WHERE TopId IS NULL AND etc...
```

and

```
WHERE TopId = @TId AND etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
WHERE  ISNULL(TopId, -1) = ISNULL(@TId, -1) and CultureId = @CId
```

assuming -1 is not a value actually stored in TopId.

PS: Your `WHERE CASE` clause fails because `THEN` returns a boolean expression which is not valid in TSQL.

Rewriting as

```
WHERE (CultureId = @CId)
AND ((@TId is NULL AND TopId is null)
    OR (TopId = @TId))
```

may help, but probably the `OR` causes terrible performance

Comment: The comments about performance are wrong. SQL server recognises that OR pattern as being a special case of equals where nulls compare as equal. The ISNULL is not sargable. I prefer the syntax `AND EXISTS(SELECT @TId INTERSECT SELECT TopId)` which is treated the same as the OR.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you could fix the `CASE` in your `WHERE` clause, in case you were wondering:

```
ALTER procedure hierarchicalcategoryview
    @TId int = null,
    @CId int = 1    

as
begin
    set NOCOUNT on;



;WITH HierarchicalCategoryTable (TopId, Id, Name, Level)
AS
(
    SELECT c.TopId, c.Id, c.Name,  
        0 AS Level
    FROM categoryview AS c
    --the where clause which fails
    WHERE CultureId = @CId
        AND ISNULL(TopId,-1) = CASE
                                WHEN @TId is NULL THEN -1
                                WHEN @TId IS NOT null THEN @TId
                                END


    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.TopId, c.Id, c.Name,
        Level + 1
    FROM categoryview AS c    
    INNER JOIN HierarchicalCategoryTable AS d
        ON c.TopId = d.Id 
                where c.CultureId = @CId
)
SELECT *
FROM HierarchicalCategoryTable order by Level asc,Id asc
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much @digital.aaron this also helps a lot